Fat-finger sequences: sequences of numbers as ids for items which are immune from repetition due to mistyping, etc
In real life I am a Software Quality Assurance Engineer who uses Jira to keep track of stories/bugs/issues, etc...  On a given day I deal with hundreds of story/bug/etc ids.  These ids are easy to conflate.  Conflation of ids can lead to a great deal of lost work.
This inspires the following question below.
But first, some setup.
Let $Digits = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ be a finite set of symbols. For our purposes here we will use the decimal digits, but other choices will work as well.  With this set comes a natural metric space structure given by the absolute difference of items in this set.
With this, consider $Digits^*$, finite tuples of digits, with the usual digit representation injection $DigitsOf: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow Digits^*$ with $DigitsOf(0) = (0)$ and $DigitsOf(1492) = (2,9,4,1)$, etc... that puts lower order digits of a number first in its digit summation form.
Now, crucially, consider integer-valued pseudo-metrics $d: Digits^* \times Digits^* \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ on the set $Digits^*$ and the following definition.
Definition: A set $A \subset Digits^*$ is $m$-fat-finger-immune with respect to $d$ if and only if $d(x,y) > m$ for all $x,y \in A$.
Example
Consider the pseudo-metric $d_{ff}$ defined on the set $Digits^*$ via the graph $D_{ff}$ defined as follows:

The set of vertices of the graph $D_{ff}$ is the set $Digit^*$ modulo permutation of elements, with each vertex labelled by the lowest representative in each equivalence class, where the finite sequence of symbols is read as, and ordered as, a non-negative integer.

The edges of the graph are defined as follows:  there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ if


A. $x$ and $y$ differ by an insertion/deletion of a single symbol "digit" or $x$ and $y$ differ by the replacement of a single symbol $s_{orig}$ with another symbol $s_{new}$ immediately adjacent to the old one, or
B. $length(x) = length(y) = n$ with $x = x_{pre}x_{1}x_{post}$ and $y = x_{pre}y_{1}x_{post}$ are identical finite sequences except that they differ in one position with that difference satisfying the condition $\vert x_1 - y_1 \vert = 1$.
Consider the associated 3-fat-finger integer sequence $0$, $3$, $6$, $9$, $10$, $13$, $16$, $19$, $20$, $23$, $26$, $29$, $35$, $38$, $40$ etc... defined by starting with $0$ at stage $0$ and then having at stage $m+1$ the lowest integer $k$ such that $d(x,k) > 3$ for all $x$ previous in the sequence.
Question:  How novel is this construction in theoretical computer science and/or mathematics? For example, consider the maximally $2$-fat-finger-immune set containing the sequence $(0)$.  Or consider associated integer sequences.  I haven't found much online about this, yet.
Thinking along these lines could lead to improvement in how numeric/other identifiers are allocated.

https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/insertion_deletion, https://github.com/shubhamchandak94/VT_codes/, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43248/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/84084/755,
